# error implement delete function for linked list using Python

Tags: python, linked-list

Hi I'm trying to learn Python by doing the first assignment which is to implement a Linked List with Python. I've implemented all the other functions. But the delete function gives me error when trying to delete nonexistence items. Can any one help me? Many thanks.

The delete function i've defined:

```
def delete(self,item):

        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False

        while not found:
            if current.get_data() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.get_next()

        if previous == None:
            self.head = current.get_next()
        else:
            previous.set_next(current.get_next())
```

Then I've written the following code to test:

```
my_list = LinkedList()
my_list.add(31)
my_list.add(77)
my_list.add(17)
my_list.add(93)
my_list.add(26)
my_list.add(54)

assert my_list.size() == 6
my_list.delete(77)
my_list.delete(1)
assert my_list.size() == 5
print(my_list.__str__())
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_data'

The get_data() is defined in the Node class, I don't know why the current local variable becomes a NoneType instead of Node when trying to delete non-existing items. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: `self.head`  or a varaible is a function?

Comment: You are hitting the end of the list, `current.get_next()` is returning `None` and the next time you loop you call `get_data()` on it (you would get identical behavior by deleting an item from an empty list). You need to exit the while loop when `current is None` and forget about `found`.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop only stops when you actually find the element. If the element is not in the list, then it just keeps going. Presumably, `get_next()` returns `None` for the last element, so after looping through all elements in the list `current` becomes `None`. The next time around the loop you call `current.get_data()`, i.e. which doesn't work because `current` is `None` and `None` doesn't have a `get_data` member, just like the error message says.

To solve this you need to stop looping when you reach the end of the array. You can do this by modifying the while to

```
while current is not None and not found:
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're in your loop, you need to be sure `current` isn't `None` before you try accessing its data. The easiest way I can think to handle this is to simply return if it's `None`.

```
while not found:
    if current is None:
        return
    # rest of loop
```